# Is there any way to quote string without new a real PDO object?

Tags: php, pdo

I am going to write a SQLBuilder for fun.

And to keep the query safe, I have to quote the value, for example, the value '12"3' should be '12\"3', I can use `mysql_real_escape_string('12"3')` to do that. but, this function would be removed from php, so, I am using PDO now.

But, If I want to quote string with pdo, I have new a real pdo object like this:

```
$db = new PDO($connectString);
```

and then, I and quote it like this:

```
$db->quote('12"3');
```

which means that I have to connect database everytime I quote the string.
but I really do not wanna do this. I just want to build a query string, nothing else.

I just want a function or method without db connecting able to replace `mysql_real_escape_string()`

so, is there any way to quote strings without new a PDO object? or another way to quote string without connection?

Comment: How about throwing an Exception, if connection is not established, while programmer tries to escape string ?

Comment: I think you mean to use [PDO::quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

Comment: @hjpotter92: yes, But I really do not want to instantiate a object to connect to database just for quoting strings.

Comment: Normally you want to avoid this _escaping_ of parameters in an SQL statement, instead it is recommended to use parametrized queries. Maybe your work would be more valuable if you would write a generator for parametrized queries (PHP code), instead of an SQL-Builder, keep in mind that escaping is something datbase specific.

Comment: I don't think that this question deserves a downvote. In fact, it's a sensible question which shows some adequate effort from a novice developer. I've seen many worst question around here.

Answer (score 2):

Escaping string without knowledge about how it will be used (this includes knowing what encoding will be used by database server and by the connection) is likely to fail for nonstandard settings. That's why `mysql_real_escape_string()` will in fact try to establish a connection to database if none is present, and if it doesn't succeed it will raise an `E_WARNING`.

In other words: you need to know something about the database, to escape strings properly. That's why you need the connection.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` respected the connection encoding in the same way like `mysqli_real_esc...` is doing.. Please be pleasant with my old friend! ;)... But the answer would be (imo) : Use prepared statements. Then no quoting is needed at all

Comment: Indeed. It was `mysql_escape_string()` that didn't take connection encoding into consideration. Hence the 'real' version of it.
And yes, in general use prepared statements/variable placeholders - but for this specific task I think it doesn't really matter - the OP doesn't wan't to run these queries against a database from his application, but create query strings to use elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to write a SQLBuilder exceptionally WRONG way. Practically, for some reason you choose Stone Age technology to build upon.

What your query builder actually have to do is to build queries with **placeholders** in place for the actual data.
While query runner have to accept data array beside query.

As simple as that.

Comment: Eh, I just wanna write another active record class or something else like that to operate db without sql query, like migration stuff, So, I need more that placeholders, that why I need a SQLBuilder~~~